# prettyPhoto not showing all pictures

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, prettyphoto

So i just finished a website using a twitter-bootstrap template and stumbled upon a little problem. While running the page locally, it all works perfectly, but after uploading the page to the virtual server, prettyPhoto refuses to show half of the pictures on the website, saying: The requested URL /img/gallery/gallery-04.jpg was not found on this server.

As i said, everything works perfectly when i run the page locally. I checked and double checked all the necessary scripts, and everything seems to be in order. In any case, this is my code:

```
<div class="span6 YDCOZA usability packaging">
                <div class="single-item">
                    <div class="img-box">
                        <img src="img/gallery/gallery-04.jpg" alt="Alt Text" width="960"; height="720"; >
                        <div class="single-navigation">
                            <a class="fullimage" rel="prettyPhoto" href="img/gallery/gallery-04.jpg">
                            <div class="full-image">
                            </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- .single-navigation -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- .img-box -->

                </div>
                <!-- .single-item -->
            </div>

<!-- Footer Scripts -->
<script src="js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

 <!-- Header Scripts -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyphoto.css">
 <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: check the paths & folders permissions and make sure they are accessible

Comment: Everything seems to be correct. Folder permissions are as required, and image paths are correct.

Comment: take a look at the console

Comment: I don't have access to the console. It's just a hosting package.

Comment: I mean the developer tools not the console (FireBug)

Comment: It says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) .

Comment: Then the image is not there check that it's already there using FTP or directory viewer from the cPanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was: the file paths were image.jpg, and the file names where image.JPG. So it was actually a matter a lower/uppercase in the file extension. Now i feel stupid. Oh well. We live, we learn.

Answer (score 0):

Check image path. Probably that is a problem.

Try to remove first / on image path. So it will be
img/gallery/gallery-04.jpg

Comment: The path works perfectly on the local machine. Other than that, some pictures work, while other do not, although they have the same path. Which slash do you mean? There is no slash before the first directory.